# Error installing PyAudio from pip on mac os 14

Tags: python, command-line, pip, apple-m1

I am trying to install pyaudio from pip using the "pip install PyAudio" on my m1 macbook but it gives an error.

This the the whole error

```
Collecting PyAudio
  Using cached PyAudio-0.2.13.tar.gz (46 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [33 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 112, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          backend = _build_backend()
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 77, in _build_backend
          obj = import_module(mod_path)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/importlib/__init__.py", line 90, in import_module
          return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1381, in _gcd_import
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1354, in _find_and_load
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1304, in _find_and_load_unlocked
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 488, in _call_with_frames_removed
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1381, in _gcd_import
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1354, in _find_and_load
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1325, in _find_and_load_unlocked
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 929, in _load_unlocked
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 994, in exec_module
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 488, in _call_with_frames_removed
        File "/private/var/folders/vg/yf8x9j0s3fs6n318p6h_zmmm0000gn/T/pip-build-env-67bkfpiz/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
          import setuptools.version
        File "/private/var/folders/vg/yf8x9j0s3fs6n318p6h_zmmm0000gn/T/pip-build-env-67bkfpiz/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/version.py", line 1, in <module>
          import pkg_resources
        File "/private/var/folders/vg/yf8x9j0s3fs6n318p6h_zmmm0000gn/T/pip-build-env-67bkfpiz/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2191, in <module>
          register_finder(pkgutil.ImpImporter, find_on_path)
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      AttributeError: module 'pkgutil' has no attribute 'ImpImporter'. Did you mean: 'zipimporter'?
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

What do i do ?????

I tried searching for alternatives but i couldnt find any

Comment: Do you need to use Python 3.12? My guess would be that if you use an older Python version it will work (provided you've installed [portaudio](https://portaudio.com/)).

Comment: It works for me with Python 3.10 (albeit on an older Mac OS).

Comment: ImpImporter has been deprecated since python 3.3 afaik it was removed in 3.12 .. I'd first try to update setuptools and if that does not help, roll back to python 3.11 and wait for fix.

Comment: https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/3935 looks like possible culprit - update setuptools before trying to install pyaudio... if you are above 66 - it could be issue in PyAudio  pinning setuptools to be older where the fix is present ..

Comment: PyAudio has been updated to fix this problem.